# Odoo access rules bug after install sales and purchases?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8

Steps to replay the bug.

1. Create a new data base.
2. Install sale module.
3. Install purchase module.
4. Create an user only with manage profile on Sales.
5. Try to create a client.

Just after click on save button you'll got something like this...
[image]
[image]

But I only want to give a one of my customers an profile on Sales. Why that is not possible? It's really a bug or what it is?

Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score -1):

The following things are need to done to clear your ACL(Access Control List) issues,

1. Make sure that you added the created user to the group that handles
   Sales.
2. In this case Purchase/User or Purchase/Manger
3. Make sure that the added group contains ACL for mentioned class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sathiyan S, I know that if I give AC(Access Control) on Purchases, he would work perfectly, but he doesn't need access control over Purchases module, like I said he only needs access to Sales module.